# Understanding the maths

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to understand the maths in this code that converts binary to decimal. I was wondering if anyone could break it down so that I can see the working of a conversion. Sorry if this is too newb, but I've been searching for an explanation for hours and can't find one that explains it sufficently.

I know the conversion is decimal*2 + int(digit) but I still can't break it down to understand exaclty how it's converting to decimal

```
binary = input('enter a number: ')
decimal = 0
for digit in binary:
    decimal= decimal*2 + int(digit)

print(decimal)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's example with small binary number 10 (which is 2 in decimal number)

```
binary = 10

for digit in binary:
    decimal= decimal*2 + int(digit)
```

For for loop will take 1 from binary number which is at first place.
`digit = 1` for 1st iteration.
It will overwrite the value of decimal which is initially 0.

```
decimal = 0*2 + 1 = 1
```

For the 2nd iteration `digit= 0`. 
It will again calculate the value of decimal like below:

```
decimal = 1*2 + 0 = 2
```

So your decimal number is 2.

You can refer this for [binary to decimal conversion](http://www.robotroom.com/NumberSystems3.html)

Answer (score 3):

The for loop and syntax are hiding a larger pattern. First, consider the same base-10 numbers we use in everyday life. One way of representing the number `237` is `200 + 30 + 7`. Breaking it down further, we get `2*10^2 + 3*10^1 + 7*10^0` (note that `**` is the exponent operator in Python, but `^` is used nearly everywhere else in the world).

There's this pattern of **exponents** and **coefficients** with respect to the **base** 10. The exponents are 2, 1, and 0 for our example, and we can represent fractions with negative exponents. The coefficients 2, 3, and 7 are the same as from the number 237 that we started with.

It winds up being the case that you can do this uniquely for any base. I.e., every real number has a unique representation in base 10, base 2, and any other base you want to work in. In base 2, the exact same pattern emerges, but all the 10s are replaced with 2s. E.g., in binary consider `101`. This is the same as `1*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 1*2^0`, or just 5 in base-10.

What the algorithm you have does is make that a little more efficient. It's pretty wasteful to compute 2^20, 2^19, 2^18, and so on when you're basically doing the same operations in each of those cases. With our same binary example of `101`, they've re-written it as (**1** *2+**0**)*2+**1**. Notice that if you distribute the second 2 into the parenthesis, you get the same representation we started with.

What if we had a larger binary number, say `11001`? Well, the same trick still works. (((**1** *2+**1** )*2+**0**)*2+**0**)*2+**1**.

With that last example, what is your algorithm doing? It's first computing (**1** *2+**1** ). On the next loop, it takes that number and multiplies it by 2 and adds the next digit to get ((**1** *2+**1** )*2+**0**), and so on. After just two more iterations your entire decimal number has been computed.

Comment: Thank for the explanation, great explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, what this is doing is taking each binary digit and multiplying it by 2^n where n is the place of that digit, and then summing them up. The confusion comes due to this being done almost in reverse, let's step through an example:

binary = "11100"

- So first it takes the digit '1' and adds it on to 0 * 2 = 0, so we
  have digit = '1'.
- Next take the second digit '1' and add it to 1* 2 =
  2, digit = '1' + '1'*2.
- Same again, with digit = '1' + '1'*2 +
  '1'*2^2.
- Then the 2 zeros add nothing, but double the result twice,
  so finally,  digit = '0' + '0'*2 + '1'*2^2 + '1'*2^3 + '1'*2^4 = 28

(I've left quotes around digits to show where they are)

As you can see, the end result in this format is a pretty simple binary to decimal conversion.

I hope this helped you understand a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain the logic :

Consider a binary number 11001010. When looping in Python, the first digit 1 comes in first and so on.

To convert it to decimal, we will multiply it with 2^7 and do this till 0 multiplied by 2^0.
And then we will add(sum) them.

Here we are adding whenever a digit is taken and then will multiply by 2 till the end of loop. For example, 1*(2^7) is performed here as decimal=0(decimal) +1, and then multiplied by 2, 7 times. When the next digit(1) comes in the second iteration, it is added as decimal = 1(decimal) *2 + 1(digit). During the third iteration of the loop, decimal = 3(decimal)*2 + 0(digit)

3*2 = (2+1)*2 = (first_digit) 1*2*2 + (seconds_digit) 1*2.

It continues so on for all the digits.